# in Android AlarmManager is Not wakingup properly?

Tags: android

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();           calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());        
    PatientDetails patientDetails = PatientDetails.getFromDB();
    int hr=patientDetails.getChosenTimeHourForTimeSlot(timeSlot);       
    int min=patientDetails.getChosenTimeMinuteForTimeSlot(timeSlot);        

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);         
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);         
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
    Intent reminderAlarm = new Intent(context, MedicationReminderReceiver.class);       reminderAlarm.putExtra("beforeOrAfterFood", food);      reminderAlarm.putExtra("timeSlot", timeSlot);       
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, reminderAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);       
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);         
    Calendar cal=MedicationScheduleMaster.getReminderTimeForSlot(food, timeSlot);               alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent); 



    This is My Question !!!!


    if i set Absolute Value for   
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);         
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 34);      
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 06);

    alarm is wakingup properly
```

please help me what i made mistake ????????
i build this project in eclipse with targetSdkversion is 22 and running in MarshMallow .........

Comment: Did you try to debug and get the exact values you set in both cases? Also, what are you still doing in Eclipse?

Comment: targetSdkversion is 23

Comment: yaa i get the exact value in both cases .#Shaishav